# Check Node -v version in ubuntu

Tags: nodejs

why is the following happening for me? :

```
$ node -v
v 10.15.3

$ sudo node -v
v 11.12.0
```

I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: would you mind adding some information to your question? like what commands did you run to install node, is this your PC or do you simply have a user on this pc but are not admin? this sort of information. Also the ubuntu version.

Comment: in addition to node version also pay attention to the environment variable NODE_PATH which determines where your npm installed modules live ... possibly you may want to create a shell wrapper to setup such variables then execute that wrapper ... also its good to avoid running node as root if possible - welcome to the forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstable you have to check the path for both command:

```
$ which node
$ sudo which node
```

And you will find where the commands are executed. I think that you will see two different folders.

It happens when you install a new version over the old one from a different source, especially for NodeJS. The npm package also will show you different versions.
I would suggest you remove it completely by executing.

```
apt purge nodejs
```

Check whether you have some files left of NodeJS and npm after the removal and clean it. At the end install it again:

```
apt install nodejs
```

And enjoy it.